# Validation error appears in header when canceling an "edit tags" operation

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, edits, validation

When you add 5+ tags to a question, a red dialog appear telling that you can't more than 5 tags. Normally, this dialog appear next to the tag field. Here, it appears in the header:

[image]

I've tested on Chrome & Firefox.

Step to follow, for 10k user:

- Go to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16618492/569101) (for example)
- Hit `edit tags` link next to tags
- add a tag
- cancel edit
- the red dialog will appear in the header

Other way for user without 10k

- Go to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16618492/569101) (for example)
- Hit `edit` it
- add a tag
- cancel edit
- the red dialog will appear in the header

Comment: Why does it even show when you press cancel? That is unnecessary.

Comment: Repro'd! The real problem to me is that the dialog appears when it shouldn't!

Comment: [Retag questions is 500 reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/retag-questions), not 10k…?

Comment: @rynah right :)

Comment: I'm looking at this now and was able to repro.  Stay tuned.

Comment: @rynah Yes, but a 3k-10k user doesn't have an "edit tags" button - just edit.  :)

Comment: I think this is fixed now, but be sure and check it out because there seemed to be a number of ways to trigger the problem.

Comment: @BenCollins Yep, this is fixed!

Answer (score 1):

It displays properly for me. Shows it next to the tags in edit mode and nothing on cancel.

[image]

Tested in Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer.

Comment: But you don’t have tag-editing privileges…

Comment: @rynah but he can still suggest tag edits

Comment: @CodyGuldner: The bug doesn’t happen with the full editing box, only with the inline tag editor. (Well, at least for me.)